# Android espresso - how to use dagger2 to inject dependencies

Tags: android, dependency-injection, android-espresso, dagger-2, mockwebserver

Injecting dependencies into espresso test using dagger2 is what i would like to do.

I would like a way to be able to provide dependencies for my test cases using dagger.

In particular there is a [MockwebServer](https://github.com/square/okhttp/tree/master/mockwebserver) class i want to inject with dagger. How is this done?
My project already has dagger set up. its a single component for now and the single componeent has 5 modules
which look like this:

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = {AppModule.class, NetworkModule.class, RepositoryModule.class, UseCaseModule.class, ActivityModule.class, PresenterModule.class})
public interface AppComponent {

    void inject(NetworkSessionManager target);
    void inject(SplashActivity target);
    void inject(AuthenticationActivity target);
    void inject(WelcomeActivity target);
    void inject(LoginFragment target);
}
```

AND IT WORKS FINE.  But now when i move to the androidTest folder to do an espresso test how would i use the following component:

```
    //note the NetworkTestModule.class i want to use is defined instead of //networkModule.class
        @Singleton
        @Component(modules = {AppModule.class, NetworkTestModule.class, RepositoryModule.class, UseCaseModule.class, ActivityModule.class, PresenterModule.class})
        public interface AppTestComponent

 {

        void inject(NetworkSessionManager target);
        void inject(SplashActivity target);
        void inject(AuthenticationActivity target);
        void inject(WelcomeActivity target);
        void inject(LoginFragment target);
        void inject (MYTESTCLASS target);
    }
```

what i have been doing it keeping the AppTestComponent in the main source code but it cant see MYTESTCLASS this way ?

The reason i want to inject into my class, is that i want to inject a mockWebServer class after passing it to retrofit as the baseurl like this:

TestNetworkModule.java:

```
@Provides
@Singleton
public Retrofit provideRetrofit(Converter.Factory converter, OkHttpClient client, @Named(BASE_URL) String baseUrl, MockWebServer server) {
    return new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(server.url("/").toString())
            .client(client)
            .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
            .addConverterFactory(converter)
            .build();
}

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    MockWebServer providerMockWebServer() {
        return new MockWebServer();
    }
    //....
    }
```

this way i can get a reference of the MockWebServer and use it in my tests and have retrofit work with it so i can do fast integration tests

also in gradle i am using the following dependencies please confirm:

```
 compile 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.9'
testCompile 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.9'
annotationProcessor 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.9'
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I will try to explain how do it:

In your application class you should have specified Application component which contains your API service:

```
protected AppComponent initializeAppComponent() {
    return DaggerAppComponent.builder()
            .apiServiceModule(new APIServiceModule(this))
            .otherModules(new otherModules(this))
            .build();
}
```

And inject like this:

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    applicationComponent = initializeAppComponent();
    applicationComponent.inject(this)}};
```

It is standard initialization. You need to just move component builder to method which can be overrided later.

In your android Tests package:

Now, you need to create new Application class which extends your application class where you have your dagger component initialization.

So now you can override `initializeAppComponent()` method and switch your `APIServiceModule` by the new one which extends previous Module.
It should looks like this:

```
public class MockApp extends App {

@Override
protected AppComponent initializeAppComponent() {
    return DaggerAppComponent.builder()
            .apiServiceModule(new MockAPIServiceModule(this))
            .otherModules(new OtherModules(this))
            .build();
}

@Module
private class MockAPIServiceModule extends APIServiceModule {

    @Override
    public ApiService provideApiService(@Nonnull final Retrofit retrofit,
                                        @Nonnull final Gson gson) {
        return new ApiService() {
            @Override
            public Observable<LoginResponse> login(@Body final LoginRequest loginRequest) {
                return // what you want to
            }
        }
    }
}}
```

You need to declare which `Application` class should be used for tests.
Now you need to do 2 more things:
 1. Create new runner which pointing on new App Class

```
public class MockTestRunner extends AndroidJUnitRunner{

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle arguments) {
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build());
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().build());
    super.onCreate(arguments);
}
@Override
public Application newApplication(ClassLoader cl, String className, Context context)
        throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException, ClassNotFoundException {
    return super.newApplication(cl, MockApp.class.getName(), context);
}}
```

2. Declare which runner will be used in `build.gradle`.

`testInstrumentationRunner ".MockTestRunner"`

Thats it. Now your requests will use mocked responses!
If you have any question just ask.

Cheers

Comment: This is good. I achieved it also by just creating a duplicate test component for dagger and using that test component with dagger mock. Yours is better

Comment: Thanks, I'm glad to hear it :)